# Cosmo Db how to check that if the collection is empty

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a code in to get all data in one collection in cosmo db, if the collection is empty then start to inserting.

The first time the code is run collection is empty however, `SetIterator.HasMoreResults` return True, even though the collection is empty.
Then there will be error raising `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: NotFound`, and I have checked with a collection that is not empty the code run fine.

I can use try catch to handle it, but it does not seems to be a nice solution, Does anyone know how to check if the collection is empty?

```
            var itemList = new List<T>();

            using (FeedIterator<T> setIterator = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>()
                                                        .ToFeedIterator())
            {
                while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    foreach (var item in await setIterator.ReadNextAsync())
                    {
                        itemList.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            return itemList;
```

Comment: What query are you running to retrieve document count? Have you tried doing something like `select count(1) from collection` with cross-partition query enabled?

Comment: i just try to query everything from the collection (if there is) and I suppose if the collection is empty setIterator.HasMoreResults should be False, but it is True even in that situation, so I just do not know how can we know if hte collection in cosmos db is empty

Comment: Running the query suggested by David would be simpler and cheaper

Comment: to modify David's answer, SELECT TOP 1 * FROM collection with is probably more efficient since COUNT(1) on a large collection might be inefficient for Phuong's use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexing to get empty collection in cosmos db. To do this you can use unique indexes. Unique indexes are created to only those which doesn’t contain any documents.

> Important
>
> Unique indexes can be created only when the collection is empty
> (contains no documents).

To create unique indexes on collections you can go through [unique indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/mongodb-indexing#unique-indexes)